# Apache Beam and ETL processes

Tags: etl, apache-beam, dataflow

Given following processes:

- manually transforming huge .csv's files via rules (using MS excel or excel like software) & sharing them via ftp
- scripts (usually written in Perl or Python) which basically transform data preparing them for other processes.
- API's batch reading from files or other origin sources & updating their corresponding data model.
- Springboot deployments used (or abused) to in part regularly collect & aggregate data from files or other sources.

And given these problems/ areas of improvement:

- **Standardization**: I'd like to (as far as it makes sense), to propose a unified powerful tool that natively deals with these types of (kind of big) data transformation workflows.
- **Rising the abstraction level of the processes (related to the point above)**: Many of the "*tasks/jobs*" I mentioned above, are seen by the teams using them, in a very technical low level task-like way. I believe having a higher level view of these processes/flows highlighting their business meaning would help self document these processes better, and would also help to establish a ubiquitous language different stakeholders can refer to and think unambiguously about.
- **IO bottlenecks and resource utilization (technical)**: Some of those processes do fail more often that what would be desirable, (or take a very long time to finish) due to some memory or network bottleneck. Though it is clear that hardware has limits, resource utilization doesn't seem to have been a priority in many of these data transformation scripts.

Do the Dataflow model and specifically the Apache Beam implementation paired with either Flink or Google Cloud Dataflow as a backend runner, offer a proven solution to those "mundane" topics? The material on the internet mainly focuses on discussing the unified streaming/batch model and also typically cover more advanced features like streaming/event windowing/watermarks/late events/etc, which do look very elegant and promising indeed, but I have some concerns regarding tool maturity and community long term support.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a concrete answer to such a broad question, but I would say that, yes, Beam/Dataflow is a tool that handle this kind of thing. Even though the documentation focuses on "advanced" features like windowing and streaming, lots of people are using it for more "mundane" ETL. For questions about tool maturity and community you could consider sources like Forrester reports that [often speak of Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dataflow-leader-forrester-wave-streaming-analytics-report-2021).

You may also want to consider pairing it with other technologies like [Arflow/Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview).